# How can I make this try_files directive work?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to understand how Nginx's [try_files](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive works. Nginx is running on my server and serving up the default page located at `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`.

However, I have a simple HTML page located in the filesystem at `/var/www/test/index.html`. The following config file is not causing that file to get served.  I'd like to understand why not, and what change I need to make so that it will be served.

Here is the relevant portion of `default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root  /var/www;
    try_files /test/index.html /;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Comment: what did you mean the the trailing `/` in the `try_files` line ?

Comment: Meaning the fallback option is a "/".  The character right before the ";" in that line.

Comment: well it needs to be a file, not a URI, so use $uri/ or use /index.html

Comment: `$uri/` might not work either, cause we're not in a location, it's in the server block, what are you trying to do exactly, so i can help you write it, like serve `/test/index.html` then if not process normally ?

Comment: @Jonah I think context for try_files directive is location not server.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

a very common try_files line which can be applied on your condition is

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;
}
```

you probably understand the first part, `location /` matches all locations, unless it's matched by a more specific location, like `location /test` for example

The second part ( the `try_files` ) means when you receive a URI that's matched by this block try `$uri` first, for example `http://example.com/images/image.jpg` nginx will try to check if there's a file inside `/images` called `image.jpg` if found it will serve it first.

Second condition is `$uri/` which means if you didn't find the first condition `$uri` try the URI as a directory, for example `http://example.com/images/`, ngixn will first check if a file called `images` exists then it wont find it, then goes to second check `$uri/` and see if there's a directory called `images` exists then it will try serving it.

***Side note**: if you don't have `autoindex on` you'll probably get a 403 forbidden error, because directory listing is forbidden by default*.

> ***EDIT**: I forgot to mention that if you have `index` defined, nginx will try to check if the index exists inside this folder before
>   trying directory listing.*

Third condition `/test/index.html` is considered a fall back option, (you need to use at least 2 options, one and a fall back), you can use as much as you can (never read of a constriction before), nginx will look for the file `index.html` inside the folder `test` and serve it if it exists.

If the third condition fails too, then nginx will serve the 404 error page.

Also there's something called named locations, like this

```
location @error {
}
```

You can call it with `try_files` like this

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @error;
```

**TIP**: If you only have 1 condition you want to serve, like for example inside folder `images` you only want to either serve the image or go to 404 error, you can write a line like this

```
location /images {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

which means either serve the file or serve a 404 error, you can't use only `$uri` by it self without `=404` because you need to have a fallback option.
You can also choose which ever error code you want, like for example:

```
location /images {
    try_files $uri =403;
}
```

This will show a forbidden error if the image doesn't exist, or if you use 500 it will show server error, etc ..

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  Specifically, what is wrong with the code in my OP?  I was able to get it working by putting the try_files in a location block and using a named fallback.  Are try_files directives not allowed outside of location blocks?  Or is the problem that in my code in the OP the fallback is a "/"?

Comment: ok i just checked the documentation, http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files, apparently it would work outside the location block, so i guess the problem was that you didn't have a fallback option.

Comment: This explanation is very helpful!

Comment: are you sure second condition is `http://example.com/images/` and not `http://example.com/images/image.jpg/` ?

Comment: You are right, but in the 2nd example I mean when you try `http://example.com/images`, `images` will be tried as a file first, then as a directory.
I'll try to make that a bit more clear, Thanks