# Configure nginx with two php-fpm fastcgi_pass locations

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, nginx-location

For wordpress site using nginx + php-fpm I'm interested in applying a longer **fastcgi_read_timeout** directive just to **/wp-admin** directory to avoid timeouts for time intensive admin tasks.

The only issue with the code sample below is when I visit http://webpage.org/wp-admin I get 404. When I visit http://webpage.org/wp-admin/index.php the page posts.

Using nginx **add-header** directive to help me debug I've been able to determine that when visiting http://webpage.org/wp-admin nginx chooses **location ~ .php$** over **location ^~ /wp-admin**.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks

```
location ^/wp-admin/.*.(php|phps)$  {

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
}



location ~ \.php$ {

    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;

   }
```

Comment: Silly suggestion. In your `try_files` directive for the `/wp-admin` block, you might want to try the URI as a directory (since `wp-admin` is a directory in Wordpress) as well before returning 404. So modify it to read `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` In terms of precedence, your config is correct.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked. To understand why I found a helpful link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798457/how-can-i-make-this-try-files-directive-work.

Comment: Yip, that was the intention. Glad you got it working :) P.S You can also use `curl -I http://webpage.org/wp-admin` to check headers from a command line interface (Unix), but Chrome debug or Firebug is equally good.

Answer (score 1):

- I tested change to **try_files** directive suggested by Keenan Lawrence which resolved issue for me.
- Helpful explanation of nginx **try_files** directive can be found here: [how can i make this try_files directive work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798457/how-can-i-make-this-try-files-directive-work)
- To troubleshoot this problem I used **add_header** directive, placing one directive in each location. Then with Chrome browser I opened **Developer Tools**, clicked on **Network** tab, clicked on **Record Network Log**, then loaded the test wp-admin/ page. There is a **Header** tab that you can then click on to verify where your page loaded. Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/404626/how-to-output-variable-in-nginx-log-for-debugging
- Working configuration below that includes header directives for debug.

  ```
   location ~* ^/wp-admin/.*.(php|phps)$  {

      add_header X-debug-message "This page processed from location ^~ /wp-admin . uri =  $uri ." always;

      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_keep_conn on;

      fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
  }



  location ~ \.php$ {

  add_header X-debug-message "This page processed from location ~ \.php uri =  $uri ." always;

      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_keep_conn on;

     }
  ```