# Angular 2 in production URLs are breaking when reloading the page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, build, angular-routing

I am running my app in production using Nginx server when I am loading the app and redirect to another route its working fine but when I am reloading the page I am getting 404 Not Found error.
consider if I am loading app at `www.example.com` then the route is working fine after reloading the page also.

if I am redirecting to the another route `www.example.com/about` first the page is loading but if I reload the page at the same state I am getting the error as  404 Not Found.

I found the solution for the same

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

import {MyApp} from './myapp';

bootstrap(MyApp, [
 ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
 {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```

The above solution is working fine but the problem is I am getting the URL with #

```
www.example.com/#
www.example.com/#/about
```

but my requirement is I don't want `#` in URL

even I did changes in Nginx .config file as given bellow

```
  location /subfolder/myapp/ {
    try_files $uri /subfolder/myapp/index.html;
}
```

but still URLs are getting the same error

Please any help appreciated thank you

Comment: I think [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687562/angular-2-remove-hash-from-the-url) might help you. Sorry for not being a bigger help on this.

Comment: @nvkfr the solution which is given in this link I tried but its HashLocationStrategy which give # in link www.example.com/#/about which is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
index index.html;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

# Location of asset folder
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
  gzip_static on;
  gzip_types image/svg+xml text/plain text/xml text/css
    text/comma-separated-values
    text/javascript application/x-javascript
    application/atom+xml;

  expires 0;
}
```

Comment: in my project don't have assets directory

Comment: Sorry, making assumptions from using the Angular CLI. Still, that could/should help without the assets bit.

Comment: can you please explain how the above code is handling the routing

Comment: I could try but I won't do it justice. This answer definitely can be better https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800131/5076023

But essentially we'll direct all traffic to the `index.html` and allow the angular application to look at the url and render out the appropriate route itself.