# Problem when subfoldering React app + Angular app using Ingress Gateway

Tags: angular, reactjs, kubernetes, minikube, istio

Im having problems when trying to access webapp frontends through Istio Gateway in minikube. I've configured ingress gateway to serve Angular frontend (minikube_ip:31380/home) and to serve React frontend (minikube_ip:31380/app) but when I try to access I get 404 files not found (css, assets, main.js, bundle.js, etc) --> [404 Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAUTq.png)

I've tried to write --base-href /app in build command, "homepage": "." in package.json, "homepage": "/app" in package.json and nothing changed.

The only thing that changed the http response was the following tag in index.html (Angular):

```
  <base href="/home/">
```

index.html (React):

```
  <base href="/app/">
```

And the result was the next one:
   Angular App --> [Angular project error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8d6t.png)
   React App --> [React project error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heFJW.png)

**nginx.conf:**

```
server {

  listen 80;

  sendfile on;

  default_type application/octet-stream;


  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   1100;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;


  root /usr/share/nginx/html;


  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

}
```

**My Istio-Ingress-Rules:**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ingress-gateway-configuration
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*" 
---
kind: VirtualService
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: virtual-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:  
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - ingress-gateway-configuration

  http:

  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /app
    route:
    - destination:
        host: webapp-service
        subset: app

  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /home
    route:
    - destination:
        host: webapp-service
        subset: home


---
kind: DestinationRule
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: destination-rule
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: webapp-service
  subsets:
    - labels:
        version: home
      name: home
    - labels:
        version: app
      name: app
```

**MAIN PROBLEM:**
[image: MAIN PROBLEM]

Finally, add that I've changed the mode of showing both frontends from Ingress Gateway to NodePort and accessing by NodePort they show well (e.g: minikube_ip:31040).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable istio injection on your default namespace? `kubectl get namespace -L istio-injection`

Comment: yes of course :)

Comment: As per your screens Istio is responding properly with the 200 status. Please take a look for nginx conf [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798457/how-can-i-make-this-try-files-directive-work) especially for `try_files $uri $uri` and fall back option (it looks like app is responding using default index.html because first two condition weren't met like home/index.html or app/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your ingress objects rewrite-target & path as below:

```
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
          path: /(.*)
```

and make sure you checked this [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target)

Once you tried this let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained myself wrong.
From what I'm seeing in documentation, this redirects traffic, for example, from "/app/me" to only "/me" but what I want is to do it the other way round. I mean, both applications when run locally in the root directory (localhost:xxxx/) and I want to, thorught Istio Gateway, show them in minikube_ip/app and the other in minikube_ip/home.

Maybe I'm wrong, let me know.

I added my Istio Gateway configuration file in case it gives you any clue on how to solve the problem.

Thank you very much !!

Comment: @Frankie, Actually in  my env i used react js app but didn't use istio, and also i used nginx-ingress controller .
Here is the ingress object gist  : https://gist.github.com/kisshore/3fd704db642e48c8d3faaa43fb1f5ba3  that i've used for .. Give a try similar to this or may be i'm not explored enough on istio

Comment: @Frankie rewrite =/= redirect

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use @kishorebjv's solution another way would be to make the change in the `nginx.conf` itself.

```
  location /home/?(.*) {
    try_files $1 $1/ /index.html =404;
  }
```